# using framework RSL to reduce SWF filesize

Tags: apache-flex, rsls

I'm using framework RSL in a bid to reduce my SWF filesize. I'm using Flex Builder to compile the SWF.

I notice a substantial size reduction when I compile with RSLs in my SWF. However the framework SWF which is created is pretty big. What do I do with the newly created framework SWF? Do I place this on my server and let flash player pick it up, cache and then sit back and enjoy the improved performance or is there another step?

I don't want to have the extra overhead of my custom swf plus the framework swf getting loaded(not from cache) each time the application is getting hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you have compiled your application to use the Flex frameworks as a RSL (as detailed [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_09.html)).

The framework RSL is typically cached by the Flash Player (rather than the browser -- as is the case with normal user RSLs).

When you load your application, Flash Player checks if the framework RSL is present in its cache or not, and if it is not, loads it and then runs your application.

> What do i do with the newly created framework swf? Do i place this on my server and let flash player pick it up, cache and then sit back and enjoy the imporved preformance or is there another step?

From the documentation:

> When you deploy your application, you must be sure to deploy the SWZ file to the location you specified on the command line. You must also be sure that the crossdomain.xml file is in place at the RSL's domain. To ensure that your Flex application can support older versions of Flash Player, you should also deploy the unsigned framework RSL SWF file (in addition to the signed SWZ file), and specify that file as a failover RSL.

Read through the page once.

Answer (score 0):

other than RSL swf filesize can also be reduced by using modules , avoiding embedding objects etc . More details you can get here from this article Link here

http://askmeflash.com/article_m.php?p=article&id=9