# Signed and un-signed framework RSLs in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, frameworks, mxml

Please explain me what is a framework RSL and difference between Signed and un-signed framework RSLs in Flex. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a wonderful tool called "search" on this website which could have also pointed you in the right direction.

For example:
[Flex RSL Understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498066/flex-rsl-understanding)
[using framework RSL to reduce SWF filesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657817/using-framework-rsl-to-reduce-swf-filesize)

Then after googling for "unsigned rsl", you take the first entry being an official [Adobe LiveDoc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_09.html)

There it clearly states:

> Every Flex application uses some aspects of the Flex framework, which
>   is a relatively large set of ActionScript classes that define the
>   infrastructure of a Flex application. If a client loads two different
>   Flex applications, the application will likely load overlapping class
>   definitions. This can be a problem for users who are on dialup or slow
>   network connections. It also leads to the perception that Flex
>   applications load more slowly than HTML-based applications.
>
> To overcome these limitations, you can use framework RSLs with your
>   Flex applications. These libraries are comprised of the Flex class
>   libraries and can be used with any Flex application. Framework RSLs
>   come in two versions: signed and unsigned. Signed framework RSLs are
>   cached in a special Player cache rather than the browser cache. They
>   can be accessed by any application regardless of that application's
>   originating domain. They only need to be downloaded to the client
>   once, and they are not cleared from the client's disk when the
>   browser's cache is cleared. Unsigned framework RSLs are cached in the
>   browser cache and can only be used by applications that have access to
>   the RSL's domain.
>
> Flash Player 9.0.115 and later support loading signed framework RSLs.
>   These RSLs can be loaded by applications in different domains. The
>   framework RSLs are signed and have the extension SWZ. Only Adobe can
>   create signed RSLs, and only signed RSLs can be stored in the Player
>   cache. If you create an RSL that contains a custom library, it will be
>   unsigned. You cannot sign it. If a Player with a version earlier than
>   9.0.115 attempts to load a framework RSL, then Flash Player skips it and loads a failover RSL, if one was specified when the application
>   was compiled.

Cheers